# How to extract a string between a forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this URL: https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/3.5-27451-5.png

I am trying to capture the value "3.5", which is located after the last forward slash and before the 1st dash.

I thought I could achieve it with something like this:

```
‘/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/3.5-27451-5.png'.split('/').pop().split(‘-‘).shift();
```

But no luck.  Any help would be much appreciated.  How can I do this?

Comment: It works if you use proper quotation marks: '/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/3.5-27451-5.png'.split('/').pop().split('-').shift();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture it using [Regular Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

In a regular expression...

1. the dot (`.`) represents any character
2. `\w` represents alpha numeric characters (a to z, A to Z and 0 to 9) and underscore(`_`)
3. plus (`+`) says at least one character

   > `.+` any character alteast one time, `[a-z]+` a to z atleast one time, `\w+` any alpha numeric character atleast once.
4. (`?`) stops the regex from becoming greedy
5. (`-`) is nothing but a simple character supposed to be present in your url

Here, we have three parts:

1. **.+/**: capturing until `https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/`
2. **(.+?)**: capturing `3.5`
3. **-.+**: capturing `-27451-5.png`

```js
var url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/3.5-27451-5.png";

//regular expression
var reg = new RegExp('.+/(.+?)-.+');

//executes your regular expression
var res = reg.exec(url);

// result will be captured in res[1]
console.log(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong quotation marks.

Change:

```
‘/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/3.5-27451-5.png'.split('/').pop().split(‘-‘).shift();
^                                                                        ^ ^
```

To:

```
'/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/3.5-27451-5.png'.split('/').pop().split('-').shift();
```

Comment: Good catch! I missed that. :)